# Stock Data with yahoo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

Hello this is my Code and no Matter what i try it just dosent work.
It always gives me the error :`" AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'calls'"`

```
#max.Länge: 7 Tage
import requests
#import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import date
import time
import csv
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_live_price
from yahoo_fin.options import get_calls
from yahoo_fin.options import get_puts
import os
import yahooquery
from yahooquery import Ticker

start = datetime.now()
#cdate = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  #Get Date on which the File was saved
sdate = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')  #SGet Date on which the File was saved
cdate = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  #Get Date on which the File was saved

tickerlist = ['^SPX', 'UVXY', 'SPY', '^NDX', '^RLG', '^RLV', '^RUO', '^RUT', 'IWM', 'QQQ', '^RUA']

for ticker in tickerlist:
    underlying = get_live_price(ticker)
    ticker_obj = Ticker(ticker, asynchronous=True)
    options_rawdata = ticker_obj.option_chain
    ticker_str = ticker  # Verwende das Ticker-Symbol direkt als Dateiname
    options_rawdata_csv = options_rawdata.calls  # Use calls to get the Dataframe
    options_rawdata_csv.to_csv(f"/home/magellan/DWH/LIVE/Options/Index/" + ticker_str + "_" + sdate + ".csv", header=True, sep=';', index=False, decimal=",")
    options_rawdata_csv.to_excel(r"/home/magellan/DWH/LIVE/Options/Index/" + ticker_str + "_" + sdate + ".xlsx")
```

I am very grateful for every help i get

I tried:

Retrieving the calls data directly from option_chain_data and adjusting the code accordingly. Which resulted in following error --> `"TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"`

My code should:

1. get live price of a stock with yahoo_fin
2. use yahooquery to get Ticker object chain data
3. export the data to a csv file

Comment: Can you update the code comments to the English language? Which may help a larger audience on SO to help you out.

Comment: Try `options_rawdata.to_csv or .to_excel`, no need of `.calls`

Comment: I tried it out now i got following error:
" options_rawdata.to_csv(r"C:\Users\ninos\Downloads\ads" + ticker_str + "_" + sdate + ".csv", header=True, sep=';', index=False, decimal=",")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Comment: Share full traceback of _`" AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'calls'"`_ error